# setPasswordAttribute in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I was trying to seed DB in Laravel with the given data, and i saw a snippet about HASH::make, mentioning it in The Model not in Seeder file..

TaskerTableSeeder.php

```
class TaskerTableSeeder extends Seeder{

    public function run(){

        Tasker::truncate();

        Tasker::create([
            'username'=>'junni',
            'email'=> 'junni@gmail.com',
            'password'=> 'Junaid'
            ]);
        Tasker::create([
            'username'=>'test',
            'email'=> 'test@gmail.com',
            'password'=> 'Test'
            ]);
        Tasker::create([
            'username'=>'poni',
            'email'=>'poni@loni.com',
            'password'=>'Poni'
            ]);

    }
}
```

and I Put that Code in my Tasker Model for Hash::make

```
class Tasker extends Eloquent{

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value){

        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

}
```

it is the way to make your password HASH encrypted, but i didn't find any information about setPasswordAttribute Function in Laravel Documentation.. and how many other attributes are there for which we can use such type of Functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are called Accessors and Mutators.

[See Laravel documentation for more information.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

They allow you to define behaviour when you set (mutator) or get (accessor) variables from your Eloquent models.

Another example would be

```
   public function setUsernameAttribute($value){

        $this->attributes['username'] = strtolower($value);
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: it's not that set=mutator and get=accessor. For example get mutators for dates.